# How to use a gem in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra, rubygems

I'm building a new version of a Facebook app called [Lovers](http://apps.facebook.com/mylovers/). You can find the [Lovers source code on GitHub](https://github.com/mattdipasquale/loversapp.com). I'm also building a custom gem for Facebook alongside it. I want the changes that I make to this custom Facebook gem to immediately go into effect for Lovers.

What's the correct way to organize its directory structure? Currently, it looks like so:

```
|- config.ru
|- features
  |- support
    |- env.rb
|- lib
  |- lovers
  |= lovers.rb
|- vendor
  | - facebook
    | - lib
       |- modules/classes here
```

I added `./vendor/facebook/lib` to the `$LOAD_PATH` from `config.ru` & `env.rb`. That's working, but should I be using an `init.rb` file to do this? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your gem in `vendor/facebook`, and use Bundler as Simone Carletti suggested, but instead of pulling **your** gem from rubygems, you could use the `:path` option, to tell bundler where to load your gem from.

Using that you could even move the gem out of your project's tree while developing them side by side.

Your `Gemfile` would contain something like:

```
gem 'facebook', :path => '../facebook'
```

There are a couple other problems with this.

1. In order for you to use Bundler to manage your gem, your gem needs a `.gemspec` file.    The gemspec specifies your gem's information, things like version and dependencies. Check out the [docs on it](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20).
2. There is already a gem named [facebook](https://rubygems.org/gems/facebook), so you might want to think about a different name for your gem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a `vendor` folder, I would use [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

Create the `Gemfile` and define all the requirements.
Then in your lovers.rb file place the following code

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

Bundler.require(:default, (ENV["RACK_ENV"] || :development).to_sym)
```

I usually create a `boot.rb` file in the root folder and move the code there adding `lib` to the load path.

```
# boot.rb
$:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/lib")

require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

Bundler.require(:default, (ENV["RACK_ENV"] || :development).to_sym)


# lib/lovers.rb

require "boot"
...
```

Comment: Why? Wouldn't that make it more difficult to make changes to the Facebook gem and immediately see how those changes would impact Lovers? Because then I'd have to bundle the Facebook gem first, right? With a `vendor` directory, the changes go into effect immediately.

Comment: It's not a good idea to make changes to a third party libraries yourself. This approach will make upgrades a real nightmare.

Comment: It's not a third-party library. The Facebook gem is a gem that I'm building alongside Lovers, analogous to how ActiveRecord is built alongside Rails. Please reread my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Behavior Driven Development (BDD) approach would be to build your Facebook gem in a separate source tree and test it with RSpec or some other test harness.

Once the Gem reached a functionally useful iteration, then include it in your application using Bundler as suggested.

Comment: Why is that the "Ruby Way", i.e., why is that way best? Seems like it'd be a pain to make updates to The Facebook gem. And functionality will never be complete. It's always changing.

Comment: I was really describing the Behavior Driven Development way of developing a Gem (I updated my answer). I have to admit, I am just starting to employ this method. It does take into account a long iterative approach to development.